# ng-repeat show only the first occurrence under a condition

Tags: angularjs

what I want is the "seen" only shows one time if match the if condition.

```
  <span class="seen" ng-if="!isDone">
     <i ng-init="isDone=true" class="icon icon-ok border0 font12 green"></i> seen
  </span>

  <b>{{msg.username}} :</b>
  <span ng-bind="msg.message"></span>

</td>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3n6x08aj/2/

Comment: provide the variable for the condition from outside the `ngRepeat`, maybe bind it to `msg`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `track by $index` in `ng-repeat` and for first node you can check the condition `$index === 0`

Working fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/3fmjzcb1/